# A counterexample to the epsilon-delta criterion for Absolute Continuity of Measures

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, absolute-continuity, borel-measures, radon-nikodym

Let $p>0$, and let $\mu$ be a Borel measure on $[0,\infty)$ defined by $\mu(E)=\int_Ex^pd\lambda$ where $\lambda$ denotes Lebesgue measure.  Show that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, but $\mu$ does not meet the epsilon-delta criterion for absolute continuity, namely for every $\epsilon>0$ there's a $\delta>0$ such that $\mu(E)<\epsilon$ whenever $\lambda(E)<\delta$.

I've managed to prove that $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to $\lambda$, but I'm not sure how to approach the second part.  I basically need to find a sequence of sets $E_n$ (in $B([1,\infty)$) such that $\lambda(E_n)\rightarrow 0$ but $\int_{E_n}x^pd\lambda$ does not go to zero.  But I can't even think of such a sequence in the case where $p=1$, let alone the general case.

Comment: The nastiness is occurring because the interval is unbounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully the case $p=1$ will help:

$$\lambda([a,b])= b-a$$
and
$$
\mu([a,b]) = \frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2) = \frac{1}{2}(b-a)(b+a)
$$

Taking, for example, $a=3^n$ and $b=3^n+\frac{1}{2^n}$ will give you sets $E_n$ which you can show the desired properties of.

Comment: Thanks, the $p=1$ is clear.  But how do you generalize it, given that you can't factor in the general case?

Comment: Are you sure? E.g. $5^3 -4^3 = y^2-x^2$ for certain $y,x$. I haven't fully worked it out but it might work just as well, although you'd have to think of a different inequality.

Comment: I'm thinking of the case when $p$ is not an integer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be. Think about how to write $x^p$ as a square.no integer assumption needed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is more or less that $x^{p+1}$ is not a uniformly continuous function: it grows faster and faster as $x \to \infty$, which means that $\mu(I)$ can be large even when $\lambda(I)$ is small if $I$ is located far to the right.

Being more precise, consider $\delta>0$ arbitrary and then try computing $\mu([\delta^{-1/p},\delta^{-1/p}+\delta])$.